# Firebase Database is showing after clicking Searchview. How to solve this?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Hi I am using Firebase Database with search query. I am also using offline method to store data from firebase offline. But after implementing searchview when I am opening the page it is showing blank. Data is coming after clicking the search icon. How to solve this? My application is on the playstore.  [It is the Link of the Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.picknpaste.dashboard)

And Here is my search query Code

```js
    private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {

        Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("Title").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(

                Blog.class,
                R.layout.bank_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                firebaseSearchQuery

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, final Blog model, int position) {

                final String fav_key=getRef(position).getKey();
                viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getExample());
                viewHolder.setFavourite(fav_key);
                viewHolder.favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        mfavourite=true;
                        databasefavourite.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                if(mfavourite){

                                    if (dataSnapshot.child(fav_key).hasChild("Title")){
                                        databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Title").removeValue();
                                        mfavourite = false;
                                    }else {
                                        databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Title").setValue(model.getTitle());
                                        mfavourite = false;
                                    }
                                    if (dataSnapshot.child(fav_key).hasChild("Description")){
                                        databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Description").removeValue();
                                        mfavourite = false;
                                    }else {
                                        databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Description").setValue(model.getDescription());
                                        mfavourite = false;
                                    }
                                    if (dataSnapshot.child(fav_key).hasChild("Example")){
                                        databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Example").removeValue();
                                        mfavourite = false;
                                    }else {
                                        databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Example").setValue(model.getExample());
                                        mfavourite = false;
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }
```

It is my code for onStart()

```js
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,Idioms.BlogViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, Idioms.BlogViewHolder>
                (Blog.class,R.layout.bank_row,Idioms.BlogViewHolder.class,mUserDatabase) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(Idioms.BlogViewHolder viewHolder, final Blog model, int position) {
                final String fav_key=getRef(position).getKey();
                viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getExample());
viewHolder.setFavourite(fav_key);

                viewHolder.favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        mfavourite=true;
                        databasefavourite.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                 if(mfavourite){

                                     if (dataSnapshot.child(fav_key).hasChild("Title")){
                                         databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Title").removeValue();
                                         mfavourite = false;
                                     }else {
                                         databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Title").setValue(model.getTitle());
                                         mfavourite = false;
                                     }
                                     if (dataSnapshot.child(fav_key).hasChild("Description")){
                                         databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Description").removeValue();
                                         mfavourite = false;
                                     }else {
                                         databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Description").setValue(model.getDescription());
                                         mfavourite = false;
                                     }
                                     if (dataSnapshot.child(fav_key).hasChild("Example")){
                                         databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Example").removeValue();
                                         mfavourite = false;
                                     }else {
                                         databasefavourite.child(fav_key).child("Example").setValue(model.getExample());
                                         mfavourite = false;
                                     }
                                 }
                                







                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });



            }
        };
        mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

And it is my search action code

```js
  @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    firebaseUserSearch(query);
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    firebaseUserSearch(newText);

                    return false;
                }
            });
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

Comment: Do you have the same code that exist inside the `firebaseUserSearch()` method, also in the `onCreate()` method?

Comment: Yes @AlexMamo Same code is in the onCreate()

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code to see it more clearly.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMamo. I just edited my code. Please look at them.

Comment: Have you tried to move the code from onStart in onCreate and use `addValueEventListener` outside the onclick method?

Comment: Problem Solved. I am using Cardview under RecycleView. I just edited my code in different way. And the problem solved.